# Why can't I have two ng-app directives in a given HTML page - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the output only if I remove one of the directives i.e. ng-app - demo1 and the models. Why I can't have two ng-app working at the same time. I am new to Angular JS and building up my fundamentals. I get the desired output if I run one directive at a time. So, in this example if I remove the demo ng-app, scripts and  controller, I get the desired output. If I remove the demo1 ng-app scripts and controller, I get the first part working fine. How can I get both the directives working at the same time?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Event Registration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1> Guru99 Global Event </h1>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>

    <div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
        Tutorial Name: <input type="text"  ng-model="tutorialName"> <br>
        <br>
        This tutorial is {{tutorialName}}

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('DemoApp',[]);

        app.controller('DemoController',function($scope)
            {
              $scope.tutorialName = "Checking Angular JS" ;
            }

        );
    </script>

    <div ng-app="DemoApp1" ng-controller="DemoController1">
        <! behaviour >

        {{fullName("Guru","99")}}

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('DemoApp1', []);

        app.controller('DemoController1',function($scope)
        {

            $scope.fullName=function(firstName, lastName)
            {
                return firstName + lastName;
            }
        });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The output is

```
 Guru99 Global Event
Tutorial Name:

This tutorial is Checking Angular JS
{{fullName("Guru","99")}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Docs:

> There are a few things to keep in mind when using `ngApp`:
>
> - only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first `ngApp` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) instead.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)